# Tuning the Ettus E310

Tags: usrp

I am very new to using usrp devices and am trying to learn how to tune the center frequency of either the receiver or transmitter of the E310 device using C++ API, so I have a few questions:

1) What am I missing in my code below

2) How do I get the my script to compile and run properly. Using cmake or g++? (tried both, didn't work for me.) Or even, how would I compile the example I would get from the github repository, just to make sure I'm doing it right.

I am also trying to use some of the examples as a starting point.

Thanks

```
#include <uhd/utils/safe_main.hpp>
#include <uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <uhd/types/tune_request.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>


int UHD_SAFE_MAIN()
{

double freq;

    printf("Enter RX frequency in Hz");
    scanf("%lf",&freq); 

//create a USRP
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp;

//set the frequency
usrp->set_rx_freq(freq);

//Read the frequency
usrp->get_rx_freq();


    return 0;

}
```

When I compile using g++ -luhd Example.cpp -o test, the error message I get is

> /usr/lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/../../../../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/../../../libuhd.so: undefined
>   reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
>   //usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing
>   from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

I'm not sure if this is in regard to syntax or some missing argument or something else I'm don't understand yet.

Comment: Could you be more precise on how "it didn't work"? Result? Error messages?

Comment: When I compile using g++ -luhd Example.cpp -o test the error message I get is 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/../../../../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/../../../libuhd.so: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
I'm not sure if this is in regard to syntax or some missing argument

Comment: Thank you. Please add any new information to the original question by editing it, instead of just putting it in the comments. That will increase the likelihood of you finding a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the my script to compile and run properly. Using cmake or g++? (tried both, didn't work for me.) Or even, how would I compile the example I would get from the github repository, just to make sure I'm doing it right.

CMake and g++ are very different things. The first one is used to generate a build script (a so-called Makefile), and the second is a compiler (which is typically called from build scripts).

You should have a look at the [init_usrp project example](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/tree/master/host/examples/init_usrp), starting with the README, and then just modify init_usrp.cpp, until you feel at home enough with CMake-based project building that you can adapt the project to your own needs.

As an additional node: you're doing this the *hard* way. The E310, unlike any non E-series USRP, is an embedded linux computer, so you need to compile the software for it and run it on the USRP itself, instead of being able to use your PC. This is really cumbersome for someone just getting to grips with build systems. If I had more time, I'd add some information on how you should not be building your software on the E310 itself, but on your PC using a cross-compiler toolchain, but that would only make things more complicated. 
If you can (e.g. if your lab happens to have another one), use any other USRP; it's so much easier to debug your code and your signal processing if you're actually working on a PC with a screen.

> 1) What am I missing in my code below

Hard to tell. It looks very minimal, but OK to me. You're not including *any* information on what goes wrong. I mean, probably you should have an `#include <cstdio>` in there, since you're using `scanf` and `printf`, but since you need to be used to C++ anyway to develop signal processing software with UHD on an embedded device, I don't think this trivial information helps you much.